# Findings powers within strings - Cases function

Tags: pattern-matching

Any idea which Cases statement will work for both A^2 and CA^4X^36 to find the powers?  If I set sym to these two expressions, one requires a curly brackets around the first argument and the other doesn't.

```
(* Sample 1.  Returns {} *)
Clear[x]; Clear[y];
sym = "A^2";
Cases[ToExpression[sym], x_^y_ -> {x, y}]

(* Sample 2. Returns {{CA,4},{X,36}} - as required*)
Clear[x]; Clear[y];
sym = "CA^4X^36";
Cases[ToExpression[sym], x_^y_ -> {x, y}]

(* Sample 3. Placing brackets around the first argument of the Cases \
function returns {{A,2}}  - as required *)
Clear[x]; Clear[y];
sym = "A^2";
Cases[{ToExpression[sym]}, x_^y_ -> {x, y}]
```

Comment: You're not finding powers within strings because you convert the strings to expressions before finding powers. Since `Cases` looks for matches among **parts** of the input (either a list or an expression), it will not find a match in the expression `A^2`. Its only parts are `A` and `2`. You can look at `FullForm[ToExpression[sym]]` to see its structure and confirm what its parts look like. That's why you need `{A^2}` to make `A^2` a *part* of the input expression for `Cases`. So you may want to use that `{...}` wrapper with the other examples too and append `, Infinity]` to `Cases[...`.

Comment: I think that if you take a look at Cases in the documentation center, under the section heading Scope that the fifth example may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the level specifications is what you need here:

```
Cases[ToExpression["a^2"], x_^y_ :> {x, y}, {0, ∞}]
   {{a, 2}}

Cases[ToExpression["CA^4X^36"], x_^y_ :> {x, y}, {0, ∞}]
   {{CA, 4}, {X, 36}}
```

Nevertheless, you might want to consider manipulating the strings directly:

```
StringCases["a^2", RegularExpression["(\\w+)\\^(\\d+)"] -> {"$1", "$2"}]
   {{"a", "2"}}

StringCases["CA^4X^36", RegularExpression["(\\w+)\\^(\\d+)"] -> {"$1", "$2"}]
   {{"CA", "4"}, {"X", "36"}}
```

Comment: Thanks - I spent ages trying to work that out!

Comment: @MLD Note that [J. M.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50) used `:>` (`RuleDelayed`) rather than `->`; by doing so `x` and `y` are localized and you will not need to use `Clear` on these symbols.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I hadn't noticed that and thank-you for pointing it out.